# What am I doing wrong with this variadic macro in C?

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-macros

I'm working on a university project and I made a macro wrapper of printf which can color the text, print the file, function and line of the instruction with a string error based on errno.

```
#define PRINT_WITH_COLOR(color, title, message, errno_code) printf(color "[" title "] " message " %s::%s:%d [%s]\n" RESET_COLOR_CONSOLE, __VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno_code));
```

This initially was divided in multiple printf but due to multithreading, the problem I'm facing is that when I have no argument to pass the comma remains there and the program doesn't compile.
For that reason I used the ## to remove commas around my variadic parameter:

```
#define PRINT_WITH_COLOR(color, title, message, errno_code) printf(color "[" title "] " message " %s::%s:%d [%s]\n" RESET_COLOR_CONSOLE, ## __VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno_code));
```

I thought it was working because I didn't receive any error on my VS Code but the gcc compiler gives me this error pointing on the right comma next to the `__VA_ARGS__ ,` <----:

```
expected expression before ‘,’ token
```

Edit
Here is an example usage:
I use it indirectly by calling this macro

```
#define PRINT_WARNING(err_code, message, ...) PRINT_WITH_COLOR(YELLOW_COLOR, "Warning", message, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And in my code I use it like that

```
PRINT_WARNING(EINVAL, "File %s cannot be written!", pathname);
```

The output is a yellow message in console [Warning] File foo cannot be written! filepath::func:line [errno msg]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you for telling me, I have updated my post! It seems like every macro call is going that compiltion error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually the macro expansion of `PRINT_WARNING` that eventually results in the problem, and you should use `##` there too. I think you also wanted to pass the `err_code` as well:

```
#define PRINT_WARNING(err_code, message, ...) \
        PRINT_WITH_COLOR(YELLOW_COLOR, "Warning", message, err_code, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

And the `PRINT_WITH_COLOR` macro should also end in `, ...)`

```
#define PRINT_WITH_COLOR(color, title, message, errno_code, ...) \
        printf(color "[" title "] " message " %s::%s:%d [%s]\n" RESET_COLOR_CONSOLE, \
               ##__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno_code));
```

Comment: That ## also in the PRINT_WARNING fixed the issue!! I though the params would be handled automatically by the last macro, thank you.